# How can I use dynamic variables in htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this example and it works fine in this case, but I want to redirect to a subfolder dynamically, based on the domain name. How can I replace example.com to the current domain?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^example.com/ /example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried something like this: (but getting internal error)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^$1/ /$1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The first rule is important as it terminates rewrite processings on second iteration and prevents the loop error.

Answer (score 0):

The back-reference would be `%1`, because it is from the last `RewriteCond`. But you cannot use it, because these back-references will only be recognized in the substitution, see [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> In addition to plain text, the *Substitution* string can include
>
> 1. back-references ($N) to the RewriteRule pattern
> 2. back-references (%N) to the last matched RewriteCond pattern

or in a [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) test string

> *TestString* is a string which can contain the following expanded constructs in addition to plain text:
>
> - **RewriteCond backreferences**: These are backreferences of the form **%N** (0 <= N <= 9). %1 to %9 provide access to the grouped parts (again, in parentheses) of the pattern, from the last matched RewriteCond in the current set of conditions. %0 provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern.

---

So as a conclusion, there is no way you can use it in either the rule pattern, e.g.

```
RewriteRule pattern substitution
```

or condition pattern

```
RewriteCond teststring condpattern
```